# Standalone multi vs. \newlstenvironment

Tags: listings, standalone

Presumably due to the side effects of `verbatim` processing, the `listings` package offers `\newlstenvironment`.  Unfortunately, the resulting environments do not work with `standalone`'s multi option.

One can get the following to run by either removing `\standaloneenv{maxpage}` or replacing `\newlstenvironment` with `\newenvironment` (which loses the verbatim effect).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

\lstnewenvironment{maxpage}{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}{\egroup\usebox0}
\standaloneenv{maxpage}% or [multi=maxpage]

\begin{document}
\begin{maxpage}
This is a test. 
\textbullet $\sin x^2$
And it has more than one line.
In fact, it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on until is extends quite far.
\end{maxpage}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get both to work together?

Comment: I would use a twolayer method: maxpageout for standalone and maxpage for listings.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that right after I logged off last night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can always use 2 environments, one for the verbatim and one for multi.

```
\documentclass[multi=wrapper]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

\newenvironment{wrapper}{}{}
\lstnewenvironment{maxpage}{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}{\egroup\usebox0}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapper}
\begin{maxpage}
This is a test. 
\textbullet $\sin x^2$
And it has more than one line.
In fact, it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on until is extends quite far.
\end{maxpage}
\end{wrapper}
\end{document}
```