# How to remove "fragile" text

Tags: beamer, code

I'm using this code to generate a frame in which my code is coloured, but I get this weird little "[fragile]" tag every time I use it. What am I doing wrong ?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,parskip,bibunits,appendix,float,todonotes,pstricks,subfigure}
\usepackage[ruled] {algorithm2e}
\usepackage{url,amsmath,amssymb,fancybox,listings,pdfpages,caption,multicol,datetime,rotating, booktabs}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,pdffitwindow=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\lstset{language=C++,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
            stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
            commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
            morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}
}
\begin{lstlisting}

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
     glPushMatrix();
     // We move the chair and table to their new location
     glTranslatef(-250.F + 220.F * i - 70.F * j,
     .0F, 20.F + 150.F * j);

     // if it's on the second row, we slightly rotate it
     float angle = j==0?-60.F:15.F*i;
     glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);

     // if we're displaying using another mode than WIREFRAME
     // we assign a material to the chair
     if(mode != WIREFRAME)
         assignMaterial(&reddishMaterial);
     chair.draw_model(mode);

     glPushMatrix();
     // we rotate the table to fit the chair
     // we scale it up a little bit on the z axis
     glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
     glScalef(1, 1.7, 1);
     glTranslatef(-170.F, 0.F, 20.F);
     // if we're displaying using another mode than WIREFRAME
     // we assign a material to the table
     if(mode != WIREFRAME)
         assignMaterial(&redMaterial);
     table.draw_model(mode);

     glPopMatrix();

     glPopMatrix();
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: fragile tag]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I cannot reproduce your output, when putting your snippet into a complete document. Can you make a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that demonstrates the behaviour?

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362570/standalone-multi-vs-newlstenvironment

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Does it help ?

Comment: @Spoutnovitch `[fragile]` is for use with the `beamer` document class, not for `report`

Answer (score 6):

**Possibility 1:** use beamer document class

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\lstset{language=C++,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
            stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
            commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
            morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}
}
\tiny
\begin{lstlisting}

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
     glPushMatrix();
     // We move the chair and table to their new location
     glTranslatef(-250.F + 220.F * i - 70.F * j,
     .0F, 20.F + 150.F * j);

     // if it's on the second row, we slightly rotate it
     float angle = j==0?-60.F:15.F*i;
     glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);

     // if we're displaying using another mode than WIREFRAME
     // we assign a material to the chair
     if(mode != WIREFRAME)
         assignMaterial(&reddishMaterial);
     chair.draw_model(mode);

     glPushMatrix();
     // we rotate the table to fit the chair
     // we scale it up a little bit on the z axis
     glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
     glScalef(1, 1.7, 1);
     glTranslatef(-170.F, 0.F, 20.F);
     // if we're displaying using another mode than WIREFRAME
     // we assign a material to the table
     if(mode != WIREFRAME)
         assignMaterial(&redMaterial);
     table.draw_model(mode);

     glPopMatrix();

     glPopMatrix();
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Possibiliy 2:** If you want to use some other class, don't use `frame`s

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,parskip,bibunits,appendix,float,todonotes,pstricks,subfigure}
\usepackage[ruled] {algorithm2e}
\usepackage{url,amsmath,amssymb,fancybox,listings,pdfpages,caption,multicol,datetime,rotating, booktabs}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,pdffitwindow=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}[fragile]
\lstset{language=C++,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
            stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
            commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
            morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}
}
\begin{lstlisting}

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
     glPushMatrix();
     // We move the chair and table to their new location
     glTranslatef(-250.F + 220.F * i - 70.F * j,
     .0F, 20.F + 150.F * j);

     // if it's on the second row, we slightly rotate it
     float angle = j==0?-60.F:15.F*i;
     glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);

     // if we're displaying using another mode than WIREFRAME
     // we assign a material to the chair
     if(mode != WIREFRAME)
         assignMaterial(&reddishMaterial);
     chair.draw_model(mode);

     glPushMatrix();
     // we rotate the table to fit the chair
     // we scale it up a little bit on the z axis
     glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
     glScalef(1, 1.7, 1);
     glTranslatef(-170.F, 0.F, 20.F);
     // if we're displaying using another mode than WIREFRAME
     // we assign a material to the table
     if(mode != WIREFRAME)
         assignMaterial(&redMaterial);
     table.draw_model(mode);

     glPopMatrix();

     glPopMatrix();
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}
%\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]